# DIV 100% width of grandparent while grandparent's width is not 100% viewport

Tags: javascript, css

I've found some solutions here but all of them assume that grandparent has 100vw which is not in my case.

Here is what I do want to achieve:

```
<body>
    <div id="grandparent" style="width: 1000px">
        <div id="parent" style="width: 500px">
            <div id="child" style="width: grandparent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Actually I need to align child's width with 5th level grandparent's width. If it is absolutely impossible with pure CSS then I would thank for JS solution.

But CSS is preferable.

Comment: How could the 'child' div have a width of 1000px, as per the 'grandparent' div, if its own parent div, 'parent', is only 500px wide?

Comment: Philip Stratford, it is easily achievable with direct width input. But I need to bind child's width to grandparent's width without child's direct width input.

Comment: It's easy to set one element's width to match that of another element using jQuery (see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/philipstratford/xaz8ah9g/), but I still don't understand how a child div can be wider than its parent.

Comment: I'm not skilled enough (lets say I'm a total noob) to explain why it is possible but in my case it is.

Comment: Ok. May be you can help with getting **current** width of one div and dynamically apply it to another div's width using js. Is it possible? So that when the window is resized and the donor div's width is changed the recepients width is also changed according to donor, not window width.

Comment: Have you tried #grandparent5 #parent #child { width: 1000px; } so in your javascript you might do something like this ('#grandparent...same as above').css("width", (#grandparent5).css("width").value);

Comment: not sure if your bit of code is reality, but, if you have a set width for #grandparent (any units but %) then a common class to #child and #grandparent will do ?? do you have a 'live' example to shows your issue ?

Comment: @user3354912 The fiddle I linked to shows you how to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/xaz8ah9g/1/

Answer (score 2):

Setting `position: relative` on grandparent and `position: absolute` on child element should do the trick. Remember though, there shouldn't be any other relatively positioned elements between grandparent and child. Consider the code below:

```css
#grandparent1 {width: 1000px; position: relative; background: yellow;}
#grandparent2 {width: 200px; background: pink;}
#grandparent3 {width: 300px; background: grey;}
#grandparent4 {width: 400px; background: orange;}
#grandparent5 {width: 100px; background: aqua;}

#parent {width: 500px; background: pink;}
#child {width: 100%; background: red; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent1">
    Grand Parent #1
  
  <div id="grandparent2">
    Grand Parent #2
    
    <div id="grandparent3">
      Grand Parent #3
      
      <div id="grandparent4">
        Grand Parent #4
        
        <div id="grandparent5">
          Grand Parent #5
          
          <div id="parent">
            Parent
            
            <div id="child">
              Child
            </div>
            
          </div>
          
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this trick but can not figure out how to apply 5th level grandparent's width to child.

Comment: @user3354912 check the modified code, and please next time provide us with an html structure that corresponds to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that one relative position lies on the way to the desired grandparent. And it can not be disabled. Is there any JS solution that will check **current** grandgrandgrandgrandgrandparent width and **dynamically** apply it to child?

Comment: @user3354912 yes, of course! ```jQuery('#child').width(jQuery('#grandparent1').width())```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this snippet directly to tag and use classes instead of IDs?

Comment: @user3354912 check my other answer, it's a JavaScript-only solution; and yes it's possible to use tag names and classes instead of IDs, but IDs are ideal in this case as they indicate a single unique element while a class could be applied to many elements, and we'll have to seek out which element is of interest to us.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution would be to make the child width position: absolute, set the left and right properties to 0, and set the width. Not the cleanest thing to do within CSS though!

Comment: Yep, and make the grandparent `position: relative`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, at least with 5th level grandparent )

Comment: Did you make the parent position: relative too?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. And it can not be changed because it will ruin other formatting(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JavaScript-only solution (notice how the child's width is set to 10px in CSS, but is reset to 1000px to match grandparent1's width via JavaScript):

```js
document.getElementById('child').style.width = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("grandparent1")).width;
```

```css
#grandparent1 {width: 1000px; position: relative; background: yellow;}
#grandparent2 {width: 200px; background: pink;}
#grandparent3 {width: 300px; background: grey;}
#grandparent4 {width: 400px; background: orange;}
#grandparent5 {width: 100px; background: aqua;}

#parent {width: 500px; background: pink;}
#child {width: 10px; background: red; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<div id="grandparent1">
    Grand Parent #1
  
  <div id="grandparent2">
    Grand Parent #2
    
    <div id="grandparent3">
      Grand Parent #3
      
      <div id="grandparent4">
        Grand Parent #4
        
        <div id="grandparent5">
          Grand Parent #5
          
          <div id="parent">
            Parent
            
            <div id="child">
              Child
            </div>
            
          </div>
          
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```